# angular cli is not loading scripts defined in scripts section

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to load jquery and bootstrap into my angular application. Angular CLI is not loading JS scripts into the bundle. I defined all the js files in `scripts` block. But i still can't see those scripts loaded into my browser. How can I fix this? My nav bar drop down menu is not working without the scripts. If I include the jquery js and bootstrap js via CDN in my index.html, every thing works.

Here is my angular-cli.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angulat-fundamentals"
  },
  "apps": [{
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "index": "index.html",
    "main": "main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js.map"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "../src/styles.css",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  }],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [{
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "angulat-fundamentals",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery": "3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

nav bar component template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular Events</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01"
          aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/events']">All Events <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/events/new']">Create Event</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" routerLink="" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
           aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start"
             style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 42px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="text">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No. If I include the scripts in index.html using CDN paths, my bootstrap navigation bar works. Otherwise, it's not.